# Can there be multithreading without asynchronicity?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, terminology

I know there can be asynchronicity without multithreading (some I/O-related tasks, for example). But could it be the other way around?
For example, this code (main thread creating a new thread to do some work and just waits until it is done):

```
var thread = new Thread(() => DoSomethig());
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

Is it somehow asynchronous? Or it should use some asynchronous pattern (event-based, for example) so that we can call it that? I know it is useless though, my question is about terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You launch a thread, and it runs it asynchronusly. But you immediately call `join` on it on the main thread, so you heavily synchronize on it. So much so that one could call it equivalent to having ran synchronously on a single thread of execution.

I can see a case to call this piece of code both async or sync (especially depending on implementation of the calls like `join`), but it's just terminology honestly - I wouldn't worry about it.

Async/sync are just useful concepts to describe behaviour of software. They're not supposed to explain every piece of code in a mutually exclusive manner.